# Alert apenas uma vez Sessão

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Queria saber como faço para que um alert apareça apenas 1 vez para o usuario na sessao, 
no caso o usuario Loga e aparece uma div com alert informado Logado com sucesso , depois de fechar esse alert
quero que ele não apareça mais enquanto a sessão estiver Aberta

o codigo que exibe o alert quando o usuario entra no sistema é esse

```
<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role=alert><b>$logado</b> você foi logado com sucesso  - 
   <a href=logout.php class='alert-link'>Deslogar</a>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que o que você quer neste contexto é por convenção chamado de *flash* de uma mensagem, aparece uma vez e 'auto-destroi-se'. É assim:

Quando faz o login, imaginemos que faz assim (na realidade como faz não é relevante, só para perceber):

```
...
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['logged_success'] = 'você foi logado com sucesso'; // acrescenta a sua mensagem também na sessão
...
```

Depois no html aproveitando o que tem:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_success'])) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role=alert>" .$_SESSION['logged_success']. "</div>";
    unset($_SESSION['logged_success']); // depois de imprimir o que queremos apagamos esta var da sessão
}
```

Neste caso, como fez o [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) da mensagem que estava guardada na sessão ela só vai aparecer uma vez porque da proxima já não vai entrar no `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_success'])) {...`.

Comment: obrigado amigo , deu certo aqui

Comment: De nada @ThallesHonorato. Ainda bem que ajudei

Comment: Eu faço com cookies, mas da próxima vez vou usar o session, bem mais simples.